# Search within an accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I've got an accordion with section headers and individual items. I'm going to link to the element ID to scroll to the relevant section but want to use a search box to search for "section 1" etc.

```js
var acc = document.getElementByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("DefinitionSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementByClassName("button");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #1AD879;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 1.6s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #45F99F;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.8s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!--  -->
<h1>Search the definitions</h1>

<input type="text" id="DefinitionSearch" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for a definition" title="Type in a name">

<h1>Section Header</h1>
<br>
<hr>
<button class="accordion">Subject 1</button>
<div class="panel">
<br>
<p class="accordiontext">Subject definition</p>
<br>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Subject 2</button>
<div class="panel">
<br>
<p class="accordiontext">Subject definition</p>
<br>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Subject 3</button>
<div class="panel">
<br>
<p class="accordiontext">Subject definition</p>
<br>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Subject 4</button>
<div class="panel">
<br>
<p class="accordiontext">Subject definition</p>
<br>
</div>
<hr>
```

So, if you typed "Section 1" into the search box it would scroll to that position on the page, possibly open it. If there's not a relatively easy solution I'll just advise users to use `ctl/cmd+f` but that's a less elegant solution even though it does what I want. I'll then just link to the ID of the header for each section.

Comment: First thing I see is that it is `getElementsByClassName(x)` not `getElementsByClass(x)`. in `myFunction()` Here: `ul = document.getElementByClass("button");` Also it will return an array.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean @RickSibley I just need it to search the accordion titles and then scroll to that position, maybe open the accordion too and hide all others. If not I'll advise `ctrl/cmd+F` because that's the same function I want.

Comment: I'm just saying you have an error in your javascript.

Comment: I've updated the post, SO doesn't recognise it as a function so I don't know what you're getting at?

Comment: because it is still wrong. it is `get + "Elements" + By + Class + Name` you have "Element"

Comment: Fancy providing an answer because you're awfully unclear in comments @RickSibley

Comment: You have so many typos in your code... Im trying to work them all out...

Comment: The accordion works, I just don't have a clue how to get search to perform the same as pressing `ctrl/cmd+F` :)

Comment: All of your `myFunction()` was messed up. Take a look at my answer below to see if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you just trying to search the Accordion headers?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so over the past few days of us going back and forth I think I am starting to understand what you are looking for. I have changed the search onkeydown to search only when enter is pressed. You can also add a search button if you like.

I coded as much as I could but it turns out highlighting text on a page is not easy. So I found a simple JS library that will help do that part of the heavy lifting. If you want more details I left the information in the code. Below is a working Snippet of everything. Take a look and see if I am missing anything.

```js
//Hilitor Settings
var highlightIndex = new Hilitor("highlightIndex");
highlightIndex.setMatchType("left");

//Globals
var input = document.getElementById("DefinitionSearch");
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

//Open Subject Accordion
[].forEach.call(acc, function(item, index, a) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
});

//Search Accordings; Highlight & Open Matching Areas
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {

    var input, filter, i, acc, panels, txtValue, searchText, searchTitle;
    input = document.getElementById("DefinitionSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

    for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        searchText = panels[i].textContent || panels[i].innerText;
        searchTitle = acc[i].textContent || acc[i].innerText;
        if (input.value !== "") {
          if (searchText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || searchTitle.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            if (!acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
              acc[i].classList.add("active");
            }
            highlightIndex.apply(filter);
            panels[i].style.maxHeight = panels[i].scrollHeight + "px";
            panels[i].scrollIntoView({
              behavior: 'smooth'
            });
          } else {
            if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
              acc[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
            panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
          }
        } else {
          highlightIndex.remove();
          if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
            acc[i].classList.remove("active");
          }
          panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

//Clear button
function clearBtn() {
  var input, i, acc, panels;
  input = document.getElementById("DefinitionSearch");
  acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

  input.value = "";
  highlightIndex.remove();
  for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        acc[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
      panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
    }
  }
}

// Highlight Script "hilitor.js" Found at: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/
// Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.
function Hilitor(id, tag) {

  // private variables
  var targetNode = document.getElementById(id) || document.body;
  var hiliteTag = tag || "MARK";
  var skipTags = new RegExp("^(?:" + hiliteTag + "|SCRIPT|FORM|SPAN)$");
  //var colors = ["#ff6", "#a0ffff", "#9f9", "#f99", "#f6f"];
  var colors = ["#ff6"];
  var wordColor = [];
  var colorIdx = 0;
  var matchRegExp = "";
  var openLeft = false;
  var openRight = false;

  // characters to strip from start and end of the input string
  var endRegExp = new RegExp('^[^\\w]+|[^\\w]+$', "g");

  // characters used to break up the input string into words
  var breakRegExp = new RegExp('[^\\w\'-]+', "g");

  this.setEndRegExp = function(regex) {
    endRegExp = regex;
    return endRegExp;
  };

  this.setBreakRegExp = function(regex) {
    breakRegExp = regex;
    return breakRegExp;
  };

  this.setMatchType = function(type) {
    switch (type) {
      case "left":
        this.openLeft = false;
        this.openRight = true;
        break;

      case "right":
        this.openLeft = true;
        this.openRight = false;
        break;

      case "open":
        this.openLeft = this.openRight = true;
        break;

      default:
        this.openLeft = this.openRight = false;

    }
  };

  this.setRegex = function(input) {
    input = input.replace(endRegExp, "");

    //The next two deal with the search, If you want to seach somthing like subject 1 and not see all words with subject highlighted then keep the settings as is. If you want to see them all highlighted then uncomment ...(breakRegExp, "|") and comment out the current setting ...(breakRegExp, " ")

    //input = input.replace(breakRegExp, "|");
    input = input.replace(breakRegExp, " ");

    input = input.replace(/^\||\|$/g, "");
    if (input) {
      var re = "(" + input + ")";
      if (!this.openLeft) re = "\\b" + re;
      if (!this.openRight) re = re + "\\b";
      matchRegExp = new RegExp(re, "i");
      return matchRegExp;
    }
    return false;
  };

  this.getRegex = function() {
    var retval = matchRegExp.toString();
    retval = retval.replace(/(^\/(\\b)?|\(|\)|(\\b)?\/i$)/g, "");
    retval = retval.replace(/\|/g, " ");
    return retval;
  };

  // recursively apply word highlighting
  this.hiliteWords = function(node) {
    if (node === undefined || !node) return;
    if (!matchRegExp) return;
    if (skipTags.test(node.nodeName)) return;

    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
      for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
        this.hiliteWords(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // NODE_TEXT
      if ((nv = node.nodeValue) && (regs = matchRegExp.exec(nv))) {
        if (!wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()]) {
          wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()] = colors[colorIdx++ % colors.length];
        }

        var match = document.createElement(hiliteTag);
        match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
        match.style.backgroundColor = wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()];
        match.style.color = "#000";

        var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
        after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);
      }
    };
  };

  // remove highlighting
  this.remove = function() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName(hiliteTag);
    while (arr.length && (el = arr[0])) {
      var parent = el.parentNode;
      parent.replaceChild(el.firstChild, el);
      parent.normalize();
    }
  };

  // start highlighting at target node
  this.apply = function(input) {
    this.remove();
    if (input === undefined || !input) return;
    if (this.setRegex(input)) {
      this.hiliteWords(targetNode);
    }
    return matchRegExp;
  };

}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #1AD879;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 1.6s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #45F99F;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.8s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h1>Search the definitions</h1>

<input type="text" id="DefinitionSearch" placeholder="Search for a definition" title="Type in a name">
<button type="button" id="clearHighlight" onclick="clearBtn();">Clear</button>


<h1>Section Header</h1>
<br>
<div id="highlightIndex">
  <hr>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">hello</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">world</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">definition.</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 4</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">definition with more text.</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 5</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">make the page longer</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 6</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">to see the scroll effect</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 7</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">stackoverflow</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 8</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">many subjects</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 9</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">this is the end.</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: This now doesn't do anything though unless it can scroll "subject 3" into view when you search it. Ideally it'd link to itself but the "subject 3" by ID, similar to linking to itself. I don't need the rest to disappear. Just to scroll to that position

Comment: Using the code you provided I filtered through the panels to show the desired result. So your saying you want me to build out a section of code you never included in your original post.... probably not going to be able to finish it today but I'll give it a shot. Also if someone is looking for a specific section why would you want to show the rest of them. keep them close unless they are needed.

Comment: It was easier then I thought but now you have a dilemma: "Since you have the search on key up it is going to try and scroll each time to the new value it thinks you are looking for. Are you sure you dont want to just have it search on enter?"

Comment: Yeah, anything would be great. I've been messing around for the last hour but am yet to get anywhere. Search on enter would likely make the most sense. I was initially going to float the search box but it's going to be moved now.

Comment: It really just needs to do the same as `ctrl/cmd+F` but built into the page for less literate people. As long as it scrolls to within view, that's fine @RickSibley

Comment: Would still appreciate some help, I've not got much further, @ricksibley :)

Comment: I didn't come online during the weekend. So sorry for the delay. I will see what I can work on today.

Comment: @EdgeDeveloper I have updated my answer if you want to take a look. still working on a few things to get it perfect.

Comment: @EdgeDeveloper did this ever help you? The current post is its final version.

Answer (score 0):

I have improved the code which was made by Rick Sibley.

The previous code had a bug. I added highlight removing in the not correct search after correct search. When you search existing word the text is highlighted in yellow. If you do the following search with a non-existent word hilight will be removed. In previous code this feature doestn work.

```js
//Hilitor Settings
var highlightIndex = new Hilitor("highlightIndex");
highlightIndex.setMatchType("left");

//Globals
var input = document.getElementById("DefinitionSearch");
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

//Open Subject Accordion
[].forEach.call(acc, function(item, index, a) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
});

//Search Accordings; Highlight & Open Matching Areas
input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13 || event.keyCode === 13) {

    var input, filter, i, acc, panels, txtValue, searchText, searchTitle;
    input = document.getElementById("DefinitionSearch");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

    for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        searchText = panels[i].textContent || panels[i].innerText;
        searchTitle = acc[i].textContent || acc[i].innerText;
        if (input.value !== "") {
          if (searchText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || searchTitle.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            if (!acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
              acc[i].classList.add("active");
            }
            highlightIndex.apply(filter);
            panels[i].style.maxHeight = panels[i].scrollHeight + "px";
            panels[i].scrollIntoView({
              behavior: 'smooth'
            });
          } else {
            if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
              acc[i].classList.remove("active");
              highlightIndex.remove();
            }
            panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
          }
        } else {
          highlightIndex.remove();
          if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
            acc[i].classList.remove("active");
          }
          panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

//Clear button
function clearBtn() {
  var input, i, acc, panels;
  input = document.getElementById("DefinitionSearch");
  acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

  input.value = "";
  highlightIndex.remove();
  for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        acc[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
      panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
    }
  }
}

// Highlight Script "hilitor.js" Found at: https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/search-highlight/
// Original JavaScript code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.
function Hilitor(id, tag) {

  // private variables
  var targetNode = document.getElementById(id) || document.body;
  var hiliteTag = tag || "MARK";
  var skipTags = new RegExp("^(?:" + hiliteTag + "|SCRIPT|FORM|SPAN)$");
  //var colors = ["#ff6", "#a0ffff", "#9f9", "#f99", "#f6f"];
  var colors = ["#ff6"];
  var wordColor = [];
  var colorIdx = 0;
  var matchRegExp = "";
  var openLeft = false;
  var openRight = false;

  // characters to strip from start and end of the input string
  var endRegExp = new RegExp('^[^\\w]+|[^\\w]+$', "g");

  // characters used to break up the input string into words
  var breakRegExp = new RegExp('[^\\w\'-]+', "g");

  this.setEndRegExp = function(regex) {
    endRegExp = regex;
    return endRegExp;
  };

  this.setBreakRegExp = function(regex) {
    breakRegExp = regex;
    return breakRegExp;
  };

  this.setMatchType = function(type) {
    switch (type) {
      case "left":
        this.openLeft = false;
        this.openRight = true;
        break;

      case "right":
        this.openLeft = true;
        this.openRight = false;
        break;

      case "open":
        this.openLeft = this.openRight = true;
        break;

      default:
        this.openLeft = this.openRight = false;

    }
  };

  this.setRegex = function(input) {
    input = input.replace(endRegExp, "");

    //The next two deal with the search, If you want to seach somthing like subject 1 and not see all words with subject highlighted then keep the settings as is. If you want to see them all highlighted then uncomment ...(breakRegExp, "|") and comment out the current setting ...(breakRegExp, " ")

    //input = input.replace(breakRegExp, "|");
    input = input.replace(breakRegExp, " ");

    input = input.replace(/^\||\|$/g, "");
    if (input) {
      var re = "(" + input + ")";
      if (!this.openLeft) re = "\\b" + re;
      if (!this.openRight) re = re + "\\b";
      matchRegExp = new RegExp(re, "i");
      return matchRegExp;
    }
    return false;
  };

  this.getRegex = function() {
    var retval = matchRegExp.toString();
    retval = retval.replace(/(^\/(\\b)?|\(|\)|(\\b)?\/i$)/g, "");
    retval = retval.replace(/\|/g, " ");
    return retval;
  };

  // recursively apply word highlighting
  this.hiliteWords = function(node) {
    if (node === undefined || !node) return;
    if (!matchRegExp) return;
    if (skipTags.test(node.nodeName)) return;

    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
      for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++)
        this.hiliteWords(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
    if (node.nodeType == 3) { // NODE_TEXT
      if ((nv = node.nodeValue) && (regs = matchRegExp.exec(nv))) {
        if (!wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()]) {
          wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()] = colors[colorIdx++ % colors.length];
        }

        var match = document.createElement(hiliteTag);
        match.appendChild(document.createTextNode(regs[0]));
        match.style.backgroundColor = wordColor[regs[0].toLowerCase()];
        match.style.color = "#000";

        var after = node.splitText(regs.index);
        after.nodeValue = after.nodeValue.substring(regs[0].length);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(match, after);
      }
    };
  };

  // remove highlighting
  this.remove = function() {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName(hiliteTag);
    while (arr.length && (el = arr[0])) {
      var parent = el.parentNode;
      parent.replaceChild(el.firstChild, el);
      parent.normalize();
    }
  };

  // start highlighting at target node
  this.apply = function(input) {
    this.remove();
    if (input === undefined || !input) return;
    if (this.setRegex(input)) {
      this.hiliteWords(targetNode);
    }
    return matchRegExp;
  };

}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #1AD879;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 1.6s;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #45F99F;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.8s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<h1>Search the definitions</h1>

<input type="text" id="DefinitionSearch" placeholder="Search for a definition" title="Type in a name">
<button type="button" id="clearHighlight" onclick="clearBtn();">Clear</button>


<h1>Section Header</h1>
<br>
<div id="highlightIndex">
  <hr>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">hello</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 2</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">world</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 3</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">definition.</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 4</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">definition with more text.</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 5</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">make the page longer</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 6</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">to see the scroll effect</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 7</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">stackoverflow</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 8</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">many subjects</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Subject 9</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <br>
    <p class="accordiontext">this is the end.</p>
    <br>
  </div>
  <hr>
</div>
```