# How can I add a search button to this existing accordion search code?

Tags: search, onclick, accordion

I am using the code by Rick Sibley from the first answer on this post: [Search within an accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55305457/search-within-an-accordion)

Rick mentions that a search button can be added to run the script onclick, in addition to pressing enter to submit and run the search script. Can any body help me add the search 'button' functionality to this, please?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I feel like a genius - though I am obviously very bad at this.

Here's what I added in addition to the keyup event listener:

```
//Search Accordings; Highlight & Open Matching Areas ON SEARCH BUTTON CLICK


function searchBtn() {
var input, filter, i, acc, panels, txtValue, searchText, searchTitle;
input = document.getElementById("keywordSearch");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
panels = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

for (i = 0; i < panels.length; i++) {
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    searchText = panels[i].textContent || panels[i].innerText;
    searchTitle = acc[i].textContent || acc[i].innerText;
    if (input.value !== "") {
      if (searchText.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || searchTitle.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        if (!acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
          acc[i].classList.add("active");
        }
        highlightIndex.apply(filter);
        panels[i].style.maxHeight = panels[i].scrollHeight + "px";
        panels[i].scrollIntoView({
          behavior: 'smooth'
        });
      } else {
        if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
          acc[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
      }
    } else {
      highlightIndex.remove();
      if (acc[i].classList.contains("active")) {
        acc[i].classList.remove("active");
      }
      panels[i].style.maxHeight = null;
    }
  }
}
```

}

With the following button added in html

`<button type="submit" id="searchBtn" onclick="searchBtn();">Search</button>`